# updating related list

Tags: list, related-list, create-records

```
List<Opportunity> op = [
    SELECT Id,AccountId, External_Id__c, StageName, Sales_Office__c,
           Held_or_Purchased_Model_Lookup__c, Subdivision__c, Lot__c,
           Hold_Expiry_Date__c, Sales_Agent_Lookup__c, Real_Estate_Agent__c
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE External_Id__c =: externalId
];

Purchased_Home__c purchasedHome = new Purchased_Home__c (
    Account_Name__c  = op.AccountId,                                                           
    External_ID__c  = op.External_Id__c,                                                                   
    Sales_Office__c  = op.Sales_Office__c,                                                                      
    Model__c  = op.Held_or_Purchased_Model_Lookup__c,                                                                       
    Subdivision__c = op.Subdivision__c,                                                                         
    Lot__c  = op.Lot__c,                                                                             
    Sales_Agent__c  = op.Sales_Agent_Lookup__c,                                                                                
    Real_Estate_Agent__c = op.Real_Estate_Agent__c                                                                               
    );

    insert purchasedHome;
```

code above works, but below doesn't work...

```
List <Co_Buyer__c> cobuyer = [
    SELECT First_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Home_Email__c, External_Id__c,Opportunity__c , Purchased_Home__c   
    FROM Co_Buyer__c where id =: op.id
];
for(Co_Buyer__c c : cobuyer){
    c.id = purchasedHome.Id;     
}
update cobuyer;
```

record of `Purchased_Home__c` is created from opportunity record, when certain conditions are met.

`Co_Buyer__c` is related list of op, and also needs to be created as purchasedhome's related list when purchasedHome record is created.

I'm having problem with related list part. When PurchasedHome record is created, cobuyers related list does not create with the purchased home record.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this compile? You seem to be using `op.FieldName` whereas `op` is declared as a `List<Opportunity>`.

Comment: yes it does compile, and purchased home record creates with op's fields

Comment: It seems you don't have the correct code here then. It's very clear that you have a `List<Opportunity> op` and then you are using `op.Id`, `op.External_Id__c`, etc. elsewhere in your code, which will not compile. Can you make sure this is the exact code?

Comment: List<Opportunity> op is in the same class but different method from purchasedhome and cobuyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few issues here.

1. You have the variable `op` declared as `List<Opportunity>` and that you are using it else here as `op.Id`, `op.External_Id__c`, which will **not** compile at first place as the variable is of type `List`. Assuming that is a typo and that you are using the first element from the list, say as `op[0].Id`, etc., your first part of code will work fine.
2. Your query of fetching the `Co_Buyer__c` is wrong. You have condition specified as `Id = op.Id`, which will never work. You need to specify the respective Opportunity field on the object on where clause to be able to fetch the record. The record’s Id will never match that to the Opportunity Id.
3. In the later part of your code, where you are trying to update the `Co_Buyer__c` records, you are trying this:

   ```
   c.id = purchasedHome.Id;
   ```

   which won't work because you are trying to update a record's `Id` field. You  **can never update a record's Id**.

   I think you are trying to link this record to the newly created `Purchased_Home__c` record, in that scenario you need to use something as below, and then update the records.

   ```
   c.Purchased_Home__c = purchasedHome.Id;
   ```

Comment: I tried c.Purchased_Home__c = purchasedHome.Id; before, but didn't do the job...

Comment: Are you trying to update the record or create? Your question’s heading says update and your code too, but then the question body says create. It’s a bit confusing.

Comment: update the record. Co_Buyer__c only have op info and purchasedHome__c = null. I want to add PurchasedHome__c field and update it.

Comment: I added details in my answer. You definitely need to review and fix your code here to make it work.

Comment: for(Co_Buyer__c c : cobuyer){
                    
                    c.Purchased_Home__c = purchasedHome.Name;
                }
                update cobuyer;

Comment: I fixed like above, but still not updating..

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details instead of posting those in comments. You have still got it **wrong**. Now you are using name fields where you need to have ids. I will recommend to go through the fields in your soql carefully and then put some debug logs to be able to troubleshoot your issues. You just need the right fields at right place to resolve it.